# firebase functions deployment in batches

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, github-actions

I am using github action to deploy firebase functions with command like so:

`firebase deploy --only functions --non-interactive --token ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}`

however currently all my triggered github action instances to firebase function deploy fail, i believe its due to the cloud build process timing out because the high count of functions building and attempting to deploy at once. In my case `50+`

How exactly can i deploy firebase functions in batches using github action?

Ideally, it would read the export functions from main `index.js` file of functions and deploy `25` functions at a time with some delay3(i.e 30 seconds) in between.

I am aware i can do this by hardcoding function names but i was hoping to do keep the github action simple and independent of function names.

Comment: Are you on the latest version (v9.5.0) of the Firebase CLI? If not, you might want to upgrade and try again -- we recently significantly improved reliability of function deployments for large numbers of functions.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh i will try with that. is there suggested limit for functions count for build and deployment on the v9.5.0  before batching is recommended?

Comment: It's a good question. The answer probably isn't "unlimited" but I think it's worth trying your whole set -- if it doesn't work feel free to [post an issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/new/choose) with debug logs and we'll see what we can do.